# Show that $t^{-1}(B(\theta, \eta, r,R)) = \left(\frac{\theta}{2\pi},\frac{\eta}{2\pi} \right) \times (e^{-R},e^{-r}) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

We are given the function $t: [0,1) \times (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and the set $B(\theta, \eta, r,R) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Where B is a arc segment given by two angels $0 \leq \theta \leq \eta \leq 2\pi $ and two radiuses $0 \leq r \leq R$. $t$ is given by

$$ t \left(u,v \right) = ( - \log(v)\cos(2\pi u), - \log(v)\sin(2\pi u) $$

I have to show that the following holds

$$t^{-1}(B(\theta, \eta, r,R)) = \left(\frac{\theta}{2\pi},\frac{\eta}{2\pi} \right) \times (e^{-R},e^{-r}) $$

I've tried to use $t$ on the corners of the rectangle but I'm not quite sure what I can use this for.

Comment: You haven't defined the function $t$.

Comment: @Dominik Sorry. I've added it